# DIV background not showing on Windows phone

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a website which uses background-images in DIVs.

The HTML fragment from my test page is:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="menu">          
                <span><a href="test1.html">Test 1</a></span>
                <span><a href="test2.html">Test 2</a></span>
                <span><a href="test3.html">Test 3</a></span>
            </div>  <!--menu-->
        </div>  <!--header-->      
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Test Page 1 for Windows Phone Display Issues</h1>
            <img class="content" id="HomePic" src="assets/home2_red.png" align="right" alt="AMTFP"/>
            <p>When viewed on a Windows phone using the default IE browser, DIV background-images were not visible.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>
            DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>            
        </div>  <!--content-->
    </div>  <!--Wrapper-->
</body>
```

And CSS for the background:

```
div#header{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url(assets/header.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    height:174px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;        
}

div#content, div.content{
    position:relative;
    top:16px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url(assets/contentback.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    clear:both;
    min-height:500px;
    width:95%;      
    border:0px solid green;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

The two DIVs, header and content, are supposed to show the background-image.

This works, and shows the image, on:

```
- Desktop 
    * Windows 7
        + IE 11
        + Firefox
        + Chrome
- LG phone
    * Android 5
        + Chrome
- LG tablet
    * Android 5
        + Chrome
        + FireFox
        + Opera
- other phone, tablet and Kindle devices
```

This does not work on a Windows phone.  According to the owner of the phone, it is:
"Nokia Lumia 1520, Windows 8, I think it is internet explorer mobile or 10."

On the Windows phone, there is no background image. I've tried both .png and .jpg formats.

What do I need to add/change to make this work for Windows phones?

Comment: IE10 [does support background-images](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). I tested your code on my Lumia 1520 and it worked just like it did on any other browser on my pc. Create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) where you demonstrate it not working?

Comment: Fiddle using HTML5 DocType:  https://jsfiddle.net/6e3mguwm/

Live test pages using different DocTypes (use the menu): 
http://www.amtfp.com/test1.html

If it works on your phone of the same model (and I assume same OS and IE), perhaps there is a problem with the person's phone.  The next time I see them, I will check their settings.

Comment: Works just fine. I however have IE11, not 10. But it should work on IE10 also. Check IE settings for data-savings, if it's set to strict it may leave some images unloaded when the phone is about to meet its data plan limits.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](http://oksanen.co/vk/images/uploads/345.png) - maybe he meant that the entire background didn't fit in the frame?

Comment: I'm still working on the responsive CSS for the Windows phone, so size is still to be determined. I saw the page on that phone last week, and there was no background at all, just black.  I will ask the owner to check the data settings.

Comment: I got my hands on that Windows phone this weekend (Okay, it's my mother's.  She's the only one I know with a Windows phone, and I'm a bad son for not seeing her more :} )  No difference with the data-saving settings, but it appears her phone is not showing proper CSS for any site. Putting this on the back-burner for now.